# Cannot install arithmoi on OS X Yosemite Haskell version ghc 7.10.1

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal-install

I have been trying to install the "arithmoi" package on ghc 7.10.1 OS X Yosemite, but when I try `cabal install arithmoi` I keep getting the error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: arithmoi-0.4.1.2 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of arithmoi-0.4.1.2)
rejecting: base-4.8.0.0/installed-901... (conflict: base =>
integer-gmp==1.0.0.0/installed-3c9..., arithmoi => integer-gmp<1)
rejecting: base-4.8.0.0, 4.7.0.2, 4.7.0.1, 4.7.0.0, 4.6.0.1, 4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0,
4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0, 4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0, 4.3.0.0, 4.2.0.2, 4.2.0.1, 4.2.0.0,
4.1.0.0, 4.0.0.0, 3.0.3.2, 3.0.3.1 (global constraint requires installed
instance)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Arithmoi is not terribly stable at the moment, and its code is frankly terrifying. Don't use its prime sieve code (it sometimes segfaults) and think twice about using the rest. The package has a new maintainer, who intends to replace large sections of the codebase. It may be wise to wait for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `cabal update`.  Arithmoi version 0.4.1.3 is out, which fixes the bound issue on integer-gmp.